# How to pass a model to a controller on another area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a model and want to pass it to a controller on another area.

This is my default action but does not work:

```
public ActionResult defaultAction()
{
    Class1 myclass = new Class1() { name = "xxx" };

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "MemberHome", 
                             new { area = "member",model=myclass});
}
```

Action in another area:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Class1 c)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass a complex object of type `Class1` to `RedirectToAction`, which is done via url string, and therefore can not accept that. You could change the parameters you are sending,

or use TempData:

```
TempData["class1"] = myclass;
```

then in your Index action retrieve it

```
Class1 c = TempData["class1"] as Class1;
```

Comment: then how it works when you want to pass a complex object to the controller on the same area?

Comment: It doesn't. There is "pseudo works" deal if the object is serializable and is added to the URL of a redirecttoaction, but besides making the URL long and ugly, it gives the data in plaintext (obviously) and is generally bad practice. Using TempData escapes that gotcha and functions with all relevant data types.

Comment: `TempData` only lasts one request. If the user refreshes the browser, all is lost and the app will fail.

Comment: That's true, but if you are using RedirectToAction with tempdata you should be setting said data and redirecting immediately, the user should not be able to manipulate the contents of TempData via frontend controls such as refreshing the browser. This is the case for the code above, TempData will be created and retrieved without any interaction possible from the user.